# Filter all the Dictionary elements which are matching with the input string array only or any number

Tags: arrays, linq, dictionary, join, flatten

I have a Dictionary which has flattened key value pairs and there is a string array. I would like to get only the dictionary elements whose keys if split, should only contain the strings specified in input array or any numeric value.

The intention is to read the list of values for a property from a flattened object.

**Sample Dictionary:**

```
Key: "Owner.0.Alias", Value: "Jo"
Key: "Owner.0.Name", Value: "John"
Key: "Owner.0.ReportsTo.Alias", Value: "Sam"
Key: "Owner.0.ReportsTo.Name", Value: "Samantha"    
Key: "Owner.1.Alias", Value: "Ma"
Key: "Owner.1.Name", Value: "Mary"
Key: "Owner.1.ReportsTo.Alias", Value: "Geo"
Key: "Owner.1.ReportsTo.Name", Value: "George"    
Key: "Manager.Alias", Value:"Ke"
Key: "Manager.Name", Value:"Ken"
```

Input array -

```
string str = Owners.Alias;
var subStringArr = str.Split('.');

**Input array will have** : [0]: Owners, [1]:Alias
```

I would like to filter all Dictionary elements which are having keywords "Owners"/"Alias"/"Number" from the above list.

```
**Expected output: **
Key: Owner.0.Alias, Value: Jo
Key: Owner.1.Alias, Value: Ma
```

Please note: The hierarchy level of the Dictionary key can be any long. The level is not known.

I have tried few approaches to filter the dictionary by using join/intercept/contains. The problem I faced is that the filtered dictionary will also have some additional keywords(like reportsTo) then the input string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following. I have split the query into sub query for readability.

```
var intial = dictionary.Keys.Select(c=> c.Split('.'));
var intermediate = intial.Where(x=>x
                            .Except(subStringArr)
                            .All(c=>Regex.IsMatch(c, @"^\d+$")));

var result =  intermediate.Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string,string>(string.Join(".",x), dictionary[string.Join(".",x)]))
                        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, y=>y.Value);
```

For input

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>{
["Owner.0.Alias"] = "Jo",
["Owner.0.Name"] = "John",
["Owner.0.ReportsTo.Alias"] = "Sam",
["Owner.0.ReportsTo.Name"] = "Samantha",
["Owner.1.Alias"] = "Ma",
["Owner.1.Name"] = "Mary",
["Owner.1.ReportsTo.Alias"] = "Geo",
["Owner.1.ReportsTo.Name"] = "George",
["Manager.Alias"] = "Ke",
["Manager.Name"] = "Ken",
};

string str = "Owner.Alias";
var subStringArr = str.Split('.');
```

You will get output as

```
Key: Owner.0.Alias, Value: Jo
Key: Owner.1.Alias, Value: Ma
```

General Idea:

1. Split Keys using "." into array
2. Ensure subStringArray is subset of  array in Step 1
3. Ensure Any remaining element of a successful subset match in Step2 is a number
4. Form Final Result

**Update** (Based on comments)

To ensure the result is achieved even when the input array is larger than dictionary key length, for example("Persona.Requestor.Owner.ReportsTo.Name"), you can alter the intermediate query as

```
var intermediate = intial.Where(x=>  (subStringArr.Count() > x.Count()?
                                            subStringArr.Except(x)
                                           :x.Except(subStringArr))
                            .All(c=>Regex.IsMatch(c, @"^\d+$")));
```

This would help parse Keys as "Persona.0.Requestor.0.Owner.0.ReportsTo.Name".

Comment: Worked like charm ! Thank you !
I have one query on regular expression you have used. Since there could be a possibility of a longer hierarchy, does this expression support all of the hierarchy ? It would be great if you may provide some explanation on the regex.
For eg. "Persona.0.Requestor.0.Owner.0.ReportsTo.Name"

Comment: @swatigupta Regex does work, but the length of input array (when greater than length of Key) would cause an issue. I have updated my answer for such scenario. Now it would work in either cases